# How to sort a ListView using C# in windows 8.1

Tags: c#

I'm doing a query to get a the medical history of a patient, but the expiry date is shown in ascending order.

I want is to sort the expiry date from the last recent one to the old ones.

This is the query I'm using to get the medical history list:

```
var currenthistory = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Medical_History>().Where(z => z.patient_id == patient_show.pass_id).ToListAsync();

medical_history_list.ItemsSource = currenthistory;
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help.

Comment: This appears to be a list of medical history records, what's the connection to the expiry date you're sorting by?

Comment: What type has expiry date?

Comment: What is special about Windows 8.1?

Comment: yeah its a list of medical history records but after thinking of it for a while I'm gonna re-sort it according to the patient's last visit date.

Comment: the expiry date is of type DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
medical_history_list.Sort();
medical_history_list.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using .OrderByDescending(...)?

Something like:

```
var currenthistory = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Medical_History>().Where(z => z.patient_id == patient_show.pass_id).OrderByDescending(m => m.expiry_date).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: well thank you a lot that what I used and it worked :)

Comment: You're very welcome :) Could you mark this as the accepted answer, since it solved your issue?